# Python selenium how to check if a specific web element contains a specific keyword?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying to check to see if a specific div class on the page:

```
<div class="css-1dbjc4n">
```

Contains a specific keyword, for example, "instagram.com"

The code that I have so far is:

```
Search = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'instagram.com')]")
if len(search) > 0:
    print("Found what I was looking for")
```

The issue with the above code is that it searches the entire page, I need it to search just in one specific web element.

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the XPath you are using to accomplish this!

```
search = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='css-1dbjc4n']//div[contains(text(), 'instagram.com')]")
if len(search) > 0:
    print("Found what I was looking for")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebElement.find_Emement_by_xpath method. Like below.

```
ele = driver.find_element_by_class_name("css-1dbjc4n") #Webelement for div
result = ele.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[text()='instagram.com']")
if len(result)>0:
    print('You found total {} occurance'.format(len(result)))
```

Now, It will print total number of elements with text **instagram.com** inside div with class `css-1dbjc4n`

Answer (score -1):

```html
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'My Button')]")
```